# Como embaralhar nomes e cores em C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou fazendo um código em C++ e preciso embaralhar 5 nomes e 5 cores para um "sorteio".
O código abaixo foi o que eu consegui fazer até um momento, porem as cores ainda se repetem.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
string letras[] = {"matheus","rayane","nelson","diogo","jeferson",};
string cores[] = {"amarelo","rosa","roxo","verde","azul",};

int main()
{
    int i, y;

        srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    char  x = rand() % 5, y = rand() % 5;
    cout << "Letra: " << letras[x] << cores[y] << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    
}

} ```
````

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas tenho uma outra ideia para sugerir. :) Utilize o [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) para embaralhar somente o vetor de cores e depois utilize os próprios índices correspondentes para associar cada cor a um usuário específico. Assim você não precisa de criar um meio para garantir sorteios duplicados (que são totalmente possíveis e bem frequentes – aliás, é a falta desse mecanismo que cria essa falha na sua solução). Isso funciona no seu caso uma vez que o número de elementos dos dois vetores é o mesmo.

Comment: Se o número de elementos for diferente entre os dois vetores, você pode utilizar um básico de [aritmética modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) para fazer o _matching_ dos índices, mas dessa vez embaralhando o array de maior comprimento.

Comment: Boa Trade @LuizFelipe eu até li sobre o algoritimos que citou, porém eu sou bem nova nessa parte então me perco muito na lógica, digamos que eu esteja aprendendo na "raça". 
Não querendo abusar... mas você poderia me ajudar mais um pouquinho explicando como funciona o algoritimo e quais as funções que eu uso para implementá-lo no meu código ? 
Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, você quer que as letras (nomes)  e cores apareçam uma única vez? Se for isso, uma sugestão seria substituir os arrays por vectors e apagar do vetor os elementos já escolhidos.

Answer (score 1):

Isso sempre gera confusão, talvez pelo modo como tentam ensinar isso nas escolas e nos livros.

O que você quer não é gerar números aleatórios: você quer uma
permutação dos valores originais.

Eis o caminho comum nessas horas:

- confundindo permutação com sorteio o programador escreve `n` chamadas a `rand()` por exemplo e sorteia os `n` números
- frustrado ao perceber que os números se repetem o programador cria um loop e um vetor e marca os números que já saíram
- eventualmente descobre que par um "sorteio" de 100 números chamou como 6.000 vezes a tal `rand()`

Isso é como se no bingo da igreja os caras retornassem os números sorteados ao globo a cada sorteio. E alguém ficasse controlando se o número já saiu.

No bingo os números não voltam, como não voltam nos sorteios da loteria. Esses ficam em exibição numa canaleta para todo mundo poder conferir, e é claro que não vão repetir. A primeira coisa que os auditores fazem é conferir se tem uma e uma só bolinha com cada número.

Esse é o "algoritmo" **Fisher-Yates**

#### O tal algoritmo *Fisher-Yates*

Se eu fosse um desses, o Fisher ou o Yates :D  não ia querer meu nome e toda essa aura de sofisticação para descrever um tal "algoritmo". Eis o que é esse algoritmo, com o seu exemplo das cores do seu próprio código C++:

```
    string cores[] = {"amarelo","rosa","roxo","verde","azul",};
```

Tem 5 cores aí. Em C++

```
    int total = sizeof(cores)/sizeof(string)
```

Talvez fosse mais simples usar um vetor. C++ é uma linguagem muito mais expressiva que C. E vetores já tem um tamanho, e podem aumentar dinamicamente sem ter que alocar memória e coisas assim

#### De volta ao algoritmo, passo a passo

Esse "algoritmo" é a expressão do óbvio e ele acaba parecendo complexo, em especial porque quando se pensa num sorteio parece que sempre se começa a pensar em números aleatórios e não em uma permutação.

Pense no sorteio da loteria da Caixa Economica : Tem lá as 60 bolinhas iguais da Mega Sena. No seu caso são 5 cores

Escolha uma das cores, por exemplo usando `rand()` como fez. Vem um valor entre `0` e `RAND_MAX`. Aí você pega esse valor, divide pelo número de cores e pega o resto: vai claro ser um número entre 0 e 4.

Use isso como índice para pegar uma cor... 4, por exemplo: então tira a cor 4, `"azul"`. Sobraram 4 cores. Use `rand()` e tire outra cor: `rand() % 4`. 3 por exemplo, e tira o `"verde"`

Restam 3 cores. `rand() % 3` vem 0 por exemplo e tira a primeira cor, `"amarelo"`.

Restam 2 cores. `rand() % 2` vem 0 por exemplo e tira a primeira cor: `"rosa"`

Resta 1 cor, o `"roxo"` e terminou o sorteio.

Isso é o algoritmo de fisher-yates, o que uma criança faria com um baralho, o que a CEF faz com as bolinhas.

**Porque a criança usa esse "algortimo" com sucesso?** Porque ela vai tirando as cartas do maço e ao estilo [Highlander](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091203/), ao final só resta uma.

**Porque a [Caixa Econômica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIipW-aTYlA) e o bingo da igreja usam esse "algoritmo" com sucesso?** Porque as bolinhas sorteadas saem do globo do sorteio e tem uma e uma só bolinha com cada número. E elas são iguais, tem o mesmo tamanho e peso.

#### Exemplo em C++, com duas vezes o mesmo sorteio

Vou mostrar um exemplo em C++ com as suas cores. Não recomendo escrever assim, é apenas um exemplo passo a passo. Se não está familiarizada com as funções usadas eis um mínimo resumo: `push_back()` insere no vetor, `erase()` apaga, `size()` devolve o tamanho do vetor. Um vetor pode ter qualquer coisa dentro. Nesse caso são as strings. Não precisa usar isso. Fiz assim porque é simples de ver. Como eu disse, C++ não é C. Tem muitas maneiras melhores de fazer isso.

É preciso algum tipo de representação para o algoritmo, a tal abstração. E o que se faz é usar um vetor numerado, exatamente como as bolinhas da CEF. E faz os sorteios usando esse vetor de "bolinhas". Isso é o que deve estar lá no link que mostrei acima. O vetor em C++ já é meio caminho andado porque pode acessar por índice e remover do meio :). Mas nem precisa disso.

### EXEMPLO em C++

#### A Saída

```
Sao 5 cores no vetor de strings
Aqui RAND_MAX vale 32767
rand() % 5 = 4
rand() % 4 = 3
rand() % 3 = 0
rand() % 2 = 0


5 cores no inicio: amarelo rosa roxo verde azul
saiu 4 = azul, restaram 4: amarelo rosa roxo verde
saiu 3 = verde, restaram 3: amarelo rosa roxo
saiu 0 = amarelo, restaram 2: rosa roxo
saiu 0 = rosa, restaram 1: roxo
 e acabou...

Novo sorteio usando um loop


5 cores no inicio: amarelo rosa roxo verde azul
saiu 4 = azul, restaram 4: amarelo rosa roxo verde
saiu 3 = verde, restaram 3: amarelo rosa roxo
saiu 0 = amarelo, restaram 2: rosa roxo
saiu 0 = rosa, restaram 1: roxo


o "sorteio" afinal: azul verde amarelo rosa roxo
```

#### O programa

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
string letras[] = {
    "matheus", "rayane", "nelson", "diogo", "jeferson",
};

string cores[] = {
    "amarelo", "rosa", "roxo", "verde", "azul",
};

vector<string> v_cores = {
    "amarelo", "rosa", "roxo", "verde", "azul",
};

int main()
{
    int um = 1;
    srand(210803);
    int total = sizeof(cores)/sizeof(string);
    cout << "Sao " << total << " cores no array de strings\n";
    cout << "Sao " << v_cores.size() << " cores no vetor de strings\n";
    cout << "Aqui RAND_MAX vale " << RAND_MAX << endl;
    cout << "rand() % 5 = " << rand() % 5 << endl;
    cout << "rand() % 4 = " << rand() % 4 << endl;
    cout << "rand() % 3 = " << rand() % 3 << endl;
    cout << "rand() % 2 = " << rand() % 2 << "\n\n\n";

    // fisher-yates :) usando o vetor v_cores
    srand(210803); // tudo de novo
    cout << v_cores.size() << " cores no inicio: ";
    for (auto cor : v_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    um = rand() % v_cores.size();
    cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << v_cores[um];
    v_cores.erase(v_cores.begin() + um);
    cout << ", restaram " << v_cores.size() << ": ";
    for (auto cor : v_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;


    um = rand() % v_cores.size();
    cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << v_cores[um];
    v_cores.erase(v_cores.begin() + um);
    cout << ", restaram " << v_cores.size() << ": ";
    for (auto cor : v_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;


    um = rand() % v_cores.size();
    cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << v_cores[um];
    v_cores.erase(v_cores.begin() + um);
    cout << ", restaram " << v_cores.size() << ": ";
    for (auto cor : v_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;


    um = rand() % v_cores.size();
    cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << v_cores[um];
    v_cores.erase(v_cores.begin() + um);
    cout << ", restaram " << v_cores.size() << ": ";
    for (auto cor : v_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << " e acabou...\n\n";

    // agora a mesma coisa num loop
    // e aproveitando para colocar as
    // cores sorteadas em um outro vetor
    cout << "Novo sorteio usando um loop\n\n\n";

    vector<string> sorteio{}; // vazio claro
    vector<string> novas_cores = {
        "amarelo", "rosa", "roxo", "verde", "azul",
    };

    // fisher-yates :) usando o vetor v_cores
    srand(210803);  // tudo de novo
    cout << novas_cores.size() << " cores no inicio: ";
    for (auto cor : novas_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // enquanto tiver alguma cor sorteia e coloca
    // claro no vetor 'sorteio'
    while (novas_cores.size() > 1)
    {
        um = rand() % novas_cores.size();
        cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << novas_cores[um];
        // o obvio: pega o sorteado e coloca no outro vetor
        sorteio.push_back(novas_cores[um]);
        // claro, tira do original
        novas_cores.erase(novas_cores.begin() + um);
        cout << ", restaram " << novas_cores.size() << ": ";
        for (auto cor : novas_cores) cout << cor << " ";
        cout << endl;
    };  // while()

    // fim do loop entao tem sobrou so uma bolinha
    // pra sortear
    sorteio.push_back(novas_cores[0]); // a ultima bolinha
    cout << "\n\no \"sorteio\" afinal: ";
    for (auto cor : sorteio) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

#### Um outro exemplo só com o sorteio final :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int um = 1;
    srand(210803);
    cout << "sorteio usando um loop\n\n\n";
    vector<string> sorteio{};  // vazio claro
    vector<string> novas_cores = {
        "amarelo", "rosa", "roxo", "verde", "azul",
    };

    // fisher-yates :) usando o vetor v_cores
    cout << novas_cores.size() << " cores no inicio: ";
    for (auto cor : novas_cores) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // enquanto tiver alguma cor sorteia e coloca
    // claro no vetor 'sorteio'
    while (novas_cores.size() > 1)
    {
        um = rand() % novas_cores.size();
        cout << "saiu " << um << " = " << novas_cores[um];
        // o obvio: pega o sorteado e coloca no outro vetor
        sorteio.push_back(novas_cores[um]);
        // claro, tira do original
        novas_cores.erase(novas_cores.begin() + um);
        cout << ", restaram " << novas_cores.size() << ": ";
        for (auto cor : novas_cores) cout << cor << " ";
        cout << endl;
    };  // while()
    
    // fim do loop entao tem sobrou so uma bolinha
    // pra sortear
    sorteio.push_back(novas_cores[0]);  // a ultima bolinha
    cout << "\n\no \"sorteio\" afinal: ";
    for (auto cor : sorteio) cout << cor << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### E esse mostra

```
sorteio usando um loop


5 cores no inicio: amarelo rosa roxo verde azul
saiu 4 = azul, restaram 4: amarelo rosa roxo verde
saiu 3 = verde, restaram 3: amarelo rosa roxo
saiu 0 = amarelo, restaram 2: rosa roxo
saiu 0 = rosa, restaram 1: roxo


o "sorteio" afinal: azul verde amarelo rosa roxo
```

Sugiro rodar os dois em sua máquina e tentar entender o mecanismo. Escreva de volta.